# Add value before specific line in Notepad++

Tags: search, replace, insert, notepad++, line

i've got a document with 38.000 lines.

I'd like to add a `<div class="kalle">` in front of each line which contains the word "Kalle" and a `<div class="susi">` in front of each line which contains the word "Susi".

Can you help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, then

Find what: `^(.*)(Kalle|Susi)`
Replace with: `<div class="$2">$1`
or
Replace with: `<div class="$2">$1$2`  if you want to keep kalle and susi in the string

`Regular Expression` must be checked but NOT `dot matches newline`